# Inclusion or element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello people I want to make sure my work is correct !

{1} --- {1,{1,{1}}}
its a subset only since here the element {1} isn't inside that set however it is a subset.

{{1}} is not an element or subset of {1,{1,{{1}}}}

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice here a good way of looking at it is for the first question is that {1} is the set of element 1, so we can see it is indeed a element of that set, and the second one is the set with element {1} and that particular element isn't in our set.